# run go executable file with file i/o

Tags: go, binaryfiles

The executable file `tapi` under folder `bin` can't create the log file (in my Mac), btw. I already create the folder `logs`

```
panic: open logs/1435584525.txt: no such file or directory
```

it runs correct with command line `tapi`

the code I use is:

```
t := time.Now()
filename := "logs/" + strconv.FormatInt(t.Unix(),10) + ".txt"
logFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer logFile.Close()
log.SetOutput(logFile)
```

the structure of files is :

bin/tapi

pkg

src/userName/tapi/tapi.go

Comment: `go run` changes current directory. Try `go build && ./executable` instead of `go run`

Comment: You need to show more context, and the errors you receive. Where are you creating the `logs` directory?

Comment: @RoninDev: That's incorrect.

Comment: @TimCooper I probably incorrectly expressed. I mean that `go run` executes binary from temp directory. So there is no "logs/" folder there

Comment: Try using the abolute path to the log file. If you move the binary anywhere it should still work. With your current code it will only work as long as the binary is ran in relative position to your log folder.

Comment: @RoninDev it is my fault, at first i did not explain correctly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "logs/", which is a relative path. If you used an absolute path (create and use "/logs/" for instance) then that would solve the problem.

I just installed and ran this successfully (after creating /logs/ and setting permissions):

```
package main

import (

    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)


func main() {

    t := time.Now()
    filename := "/logs/" + strconv.FormatInt(t.Unix(), 10) + ".txt"
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()
    log.SetOutput(logFile)
}
```

If you leave the path relative then add: "/src/tapi/logs" in the directory structure and it will work.

Under those circumstances this ran fine for me:

```
package main

import (

    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)


func main() {

    t := time.Now()
    filename := "logs/" + strconv.FormatInt(t.Unix(), 10) + ".txt"
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()
    log.SetOutput(logFile)
}
```